# C# Events do not trigger while GUI Thread is busy (drawing). How to solve?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

### Short intro to my program (Solved)

---

My program is taking an image and reveals tile after tile (guessing game).
I decided to go with fading in (manually) each tile.
Since I need the user to be able to interact with the GUI, I do the calculations and thread blocking things like `Thread.Sleep` on another thread. I also added an OnClickEvent to a picturebox (which overlays the image to reveal). => if someone guessed the image the user can click on the picturebox to fully reveal the image. (For fading I am clipping a region of the picturebox and then clear it with a color. The color's alpha value is decreasing step by step until it is fully transparent. Then I go to the next region.)

### Incoming problem

---

After each iteration I need to refresh the picturebox so that it displays the new "situation". Therefore I have to invoke the action on the GUI Thread.
Now if the time between each refresh becomes too short like 10 ms the GUI seems to be so busy refreshing/drawing the image that it doesn't fire my OnClickEvent anymore.

### The reveal function

---

```
public void Reveal(int step, int intervalFading, int intervalNextTile)
    {
        StopThread = false; // Changed by the OnClickEvent
        Graphics grx = Graphics.FromImage(Overlay.Image);
        step = 255 / step;
        foreach (RectangleF R in AreasShuffled)
        {
            grx.Clip = new Region(R);
            for (int i = 255; i >= 0; i-=step) //Fading out loop
            {
                Thread.Sleep(intervalFading);  //if intervalFading < 15 GUI is too busy
                if (StopThread) //Condition if someone guessed correctly
                {
                    grx.ResetClip();
                    grx.Clear(Color.FromArgb(0, 0, 0, 0)); //revealing the image
                    ParentControl.BeginInvoke((Action)(() => Overlay.Refresh()));
                    grx.Dispose();
                    return;
                }
                grx.Clear(Color.FromArgb(i, 0, 0, 0)); //Clearing region 
                ParentControl.BeginInvoke((Action)(() => Overlay.Refresh())); //Redrawing image
            }
            grx.Clear(Color.FromArgb(0, 0, 0, 0));
            ParentControl.BeginInvoke((Action)(() => Overlay.Refresh()));
            Thread.Sleep(intervalNextTile);
        }
        grx.ResetClip();
        grx.Clear(Color.FromArgb(0, 0, 0, 0));
        ParentControl.BeginInvoke((Action)(() => Overlay.Refresh()));
        grx.Dispose();
    }
```

### Solution

---

As adviced I used async tasks. Here is the updated function. (Yeah, I didn't update the grx.dispose() ^^)

```
public async Task Reveal(int step, int intervalFading, int intervalNextTile)
    {
        taskIsRunning = true;
        stopTask = false; // Changed by the OnClickEvent
        Graphics grx = Graphics.FromImage(Overlay.Image);
        step = 255 / step;
        foreach (RectangleF R in AreasShuffled)
        {
            grx.Clip = new Region(R);
            for (int i = 255; i >= 0; i -= step) 
            {
                
                await Task.Delay(intervalFading);  
                if (stopTask) 
                {
                    grx.ResetClip();
                    grx.Clear(Color.FromArgb(0, 0, 0, 0)); 
                    Overlay.Refresh();
                    grx.Dispose();
                    taskIsRunning = false;
                    return;
                }
                grx.Clear(Color.FromArgb(i, 0, 0, 0)); 
                Overlay.Refresh();
            }
            grx.Clear(Color.FromArgb(0, 0, 0, 0));
            Overlay.Refresh();
            await Task.Delay(intervalNextTile);
        }
        grx.ResetClip();
        grx.Clear(Color.FromArgb(0, 0, 0, 0));
        Overlay.Refresh();
        grx.Dispose();
        taskIsRunning = false;
    }
```

and the calling function that checks whether the task is running or not

```
private void pictureBoxOverlay_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (UCM != null && UCM.taskIsRunning)                                              //if it is running the function is being notified
        {                                                                              //and reveals the image. 
            UCM.stopTask = true;
        }
        else                            //makes sure that the user has to click again to start with the next image
        {
            if (index < Images.Count - 1)
            {
                PrepareNextImage();
                UCM.Reveal(Properties.Settings.Default.steps, Properties.Settings.Default.fadeInterval, Properties.Settings.Default.nextTileInterval); 
            }
            else
                MessageBox.Show("End of presentation.");
        }
    }
```

Thanks for your help ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<s>There is a short answer here. Don't call `Thread.Sleep` on the UI thread if you expect your UI to be responsive</s>

**Update**

It appears that you are not running your animation code of the UI thread. Good stuff! So what could be the problem? I suspect the 4 calls to `BeginInvoke` many times per second is causing the application message pump to flood with invoke events and delay the GUI updates while servicing them.

Fix this by  reducing the number of invokes. Do all your updates in a single invoke per interval.

This short example invokes back to the calling context only once each interval. You should call it from the UI.

```
async Task Animate(Control control, int interval)
{
    while(true)
    {
        // this line causes the method to pause by queueing
        // everything after await similarly to `BeginInvoke`
        await Task.Delay(interval);

        // all of this still happens on the UI thread

        // increment control properties here

        // check to see if the animation should end.
        if (END STATE IS MET)
        {
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

---

As a side note - you are calling `grx.Dispose` a few times. It may be better to wrap the whole code block in `using(grx){ }`. This still works with async! How? [Darkest magicks](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html).

Comment: Is `Delay(int):Task` a part of the WinForms api and if so, does it have any advantages over simply awaiting `Task.Delay(TimeSpan):Task`?

Comment: @kai `Task.Delay` was my intention and I made a mistake. Oops! Thanks for pointing it out. I have edited the answer.

Comment: no worries! Although I prefer to use the overload accepting a TimeSpan since it's more semantically meaningful. At the very least I prefer it if the int parameter is named after the unit expected (millis)

Comment: Hi just wanted to make clear that I don't use Thread.Sleep on my GUI Thread but on the Background thread I created. And the function you see is handled by the background thread.

Comment: @kai I also prefer to use `TimeSpan` where possible but wanted to remain as close as possible to the asker's example.

Comment: @lorenzalbert in that case, it is probable that your `BeginInvoke` calls are flooding the message pump and causing a delay as the application loop tries to service them all. I've seen this happen a few times before, even in WPF. You should try and do all updates in a single Invoke. This answer will provide that facility _but you must execute it from the UI_. Can you give it a shot and report back?

Comment: @Gusdor I try to do so when I am back. And thanks for your help.

Comment: @Gusdor Everything seems to be working fine even though dragging the window could be smoother ^^. I don't know if I used everything properly but learning TPL and asynchronous calls is on my todo list.

Comment: @lorenzalbert Good to hear. The window will still chop around due to the number of redraws that are occurring. This is a symptom of the immediate mode rendering scheme that WInforms employs and I'm not sure how to get around it. For anything involving animation I would recommend looking at WPF for future apps, although the learning curve is steep on that one. Happy book reading!